# python 2.7: reading a file only up to a known line

Tags: python-2.7, file-io

If I wanted to read starting from a given line I can do:

```
with open(myfile) as f:
  for x in range(from_here):
    next(f)

  for line in f:
    do stuff
```

How can I do the opposite: reading only up to a given line?

I was thinking about a for loop: is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is to use a loop that just counts:

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    for i in xrange(number_of_wanted_lines):
        line = next(f)
        # do stuff with line
```

Regarding the second part of your question, you can also read in the full file into a list of lines, then use slices:

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[start_line_number:end_line_number+1]
    for line in lines:
        # do stuff with line
```

If you don't want to load the whole file into memory, you can also use `islice` (from `itertools`) instead of list slices:

```
import itertools

with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, start_line_number, end_line_number + 1):
        # do stuff with line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    for x in range(until_here):
        line = next(f)
        # do stuff with line
    # do stuff with the rest of f
```

or

```
import itertools as it
with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in it.islice(f, until_here):
        # do stuff
    # do stuff with the rest of f
```